# I am having trouble with assigning a Role to a User when a User is created through Registration

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am trying to create a user registration using Identity. In the registration page, it ask for the First Name, Last Name, email, other basic information plus a few specific details about my project. Then I have a drop down menu with all the Roles that I have created that are options for that User to be. I know the Roles in my Sample Data work but do not work when a User is created. When I create a User and assign them a role, it completes the User creation without any sorts of errors but does not have the ability to view or do any action that the role would do. For instance, I have a Role called Admin which can view and create Users. If I created a new User that would have a Role as Admin, in my application right now all it does is create a User and that's it.

I believe my issue is in the Register.cshtml.cs file, in the OnPostAsync method. This is the line of code that I am trying to assign the user the role:

```
await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(Input.Email, "Confirm your email",
                    $"Please confirm your account by <a href='{HtmlEncoder.Default.Encode(callbackUrl)}'>clicking here</a>.");

                await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);

                await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "Member");

                return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
            }
            foreach (var error in result.Errors)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, error.Description);
            }
```

I am expecting to see on top a nav bar with links to different admin task such as "Creating a New User" and "View Users" but what I am getting is a empty nav bar at the top with no functionality. (Sorry new to asking a Question in StackOverflow and tried to add a screenshot of my outcomes to help describe my issue but can't get it to work)

Comment: Issue Solved! It wouldn't apply the role to the user because I still had code for confirming email options from Identity and all I did was comment those line of code out and it works!

Comment: If anyone has the same issue comment out (or delete) the following code:                                var code = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
                    var callbackUrl = Url.Page(
                        "/Account/ConfirmEmail",
                        pageHandler: null,
                        values: new { userId = user.Id, code = code },
                        protocol: Request.Scheme);

                    await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(Input.Email, "Confirm your email",

Answer (score 0):

I use this and it work fine

```
IdentityResult addUserResult = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user,createUserModel.Password);
IdentityResult addResult = await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, createUserModel.RoleName);
```

hope it work for you